# Ambigous redirect in a BASH script consisting 2 functions, taking 3 parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I found a bug in my bash script, and I have no idea how to fix it.

I have a main script in which at a certain point I'm calling the other script.

The other `time_diff.sh` script consists of 2 functions, and they look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function timeDiff() {
    local time1="$(head -n 1 "$1")"
    local time2="$(head -n 1 "$2")"
    pc=$(( $time2 - $time1 ))
    timediff=${pc#-}

    pc=$(perl $BVTDIR/engine/math.pl $pc $time1)
    pc=${pc#-}

    echo "Prozentdiffertenz = "$pc"%"
    echo "Laufzeitdiffertenz = "$timediff" milisekunden"

    if (( "$timediff" < "$MAX_TIME_DIFF")) && (( "$pc" < "$MAX_PERC_DIFF" )); then

# the script is doing nothing, just echoing that everything is fine

     elif (( "$timediff" > "$MAX_TIME_DIFF")) && (( "$pc" < "$MAX_PERC_DIFF" )); then

# the script is doing nothing, just echoing that everything is fine

     elif (( "$timediff" < "$MAX_TIME_DIFF")) && (( "$pc" > "$MAX_PERC_DIFF" )); then

# the script is doing nothing, just echoing that everything is fine

     elif (( "$timediff" > "$MAX_TIME_DIFF")) && (( "$pc" > "$MAX_PERC_DIFF" )); then

# the script is runing a diff and saving the output.

          diff $1 $2 >> $3
    fi
}

function recuDiff {
  find $1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name \*.TIME.TXT -printf '%P\n' |
  while read each
  do
    if [ -e $2/"$each" ]
    then
      timeDiff {$1,$2}/"$each"
    fi
  done
}

recuDiff $1 $2
```

This script is called from the main script like this:

```
/bin/bash time_diff.sh $CURRENT_BUILD_DIR $PREVIOUS_BUILD_DIR $DIFF_DIR/DIFF_RUNTIMES.TXT
```

Until the `timeDiff()` function went to the parts of if-elif statements where the script was just doing nothing, printing out that everything is fine - everything WAS fine.

Today Ive found out that when the if-elif statement goes to the last section, where it should run the diff on the files and save it to the file, I get:

```
time_diff.sh: line 34: $3: ambiguous redirect
```

Line 34:

```
diff $1 $2 >> $3
```

And the file is never created.

What could be wrong? Should I `touch DIFF_TIME.TXT` before running the `time_diff.sh` script?

One more thing - it is VERY hard to reproduce this bug, it takes an hour to run throuhg the whole Jenkins job, and I have ABSOLUTELY no guarantee that one of the things this script is testing will run longer than it should, so I havent tried any solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a shell function, `$1`, `$2`, etc. refer to the arguments passed to the function, not the ones passed to the script. In your case, you are calling

```
timeDiff {$1,$2}/"$each"
```

which passes two arguments to `timeDiff` (outside the case where you might have spaces in the arguments - you might need to reconsider some of your quoting bits), yet `timeDiff()` is referring to `$3`, which will be undefined.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the problem is simply that `$3` is not defined.

Observe:

```
echo foo >> "$3"
bash: $3: ambiguous redirect
```

Note that positional parameters (`$1` ... `$9`) are not shared or inherited. Each shell function has its own set of positional parameters.

You called your script with three arguments. But you called the function with only two arguments. That is why `$3` is undefined inside the function.

Observe:

```
$ cat foo.sh 
echo "$1" "$2" "$3"
func() {
  echo "$1" "$2" "$3"
}
func "$1" "$2"

$ bash foo.sh a b c
a b c
a b
```

Also as a general rule: put quotes around all variable references.

Comment: That gives an understanding, but...`/bin/bash time_diff.sh $CURRENT_BUILD_DIR $PREVIOUS_BUILD_DIR $DIFF_DIR/DIFF_RUNTIMES.TXT` means that the $3 was initialitzed. I am calling the script with 3 arguments...

Comment: @dziki Yes, you are calling the script with 3 arguments. However, you are calling the `timeDiff` function with only two.

Comment: @dziki I overlooked to explain that part in my answer. please see updated answer.